# Doctrine2 increment column and get value

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have an entity with a descriptor and a count.  I need to increment the count column and retrieve the value.  I could just get the entity, increment the count, and persist it, but that would be susceptible to race conditions right?  What would be the best way to do this?  I would rather not use a native query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [Optimistic Locking](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#locking-support). Doctrine will version your entity and throw a locking exception if you try to update it when it's out of date.

Comment: I ended up using pessimistic locking, but optimistic locking would have worked as well.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!